# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 - Tried many solutions, none have worked

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, dalvik

Okay I know there are a bunch of these topics out there, but I have tried just about everything I could find and still I cannot get it to work.  I have worked with my project for about 6 months with no errors, I stopped for 3 months and got back into it on a new computer and now it keeps giving me this error when trying to export a signed APK.  I have tried the following:

1. Turning off Build Automatically (and cleaning the project)
2. Changing the proguard.bat to include  %1 %2 %3 etc
3. Removing the libraries from the Java Build Path > Libraries
4. Uninstalling Eclipse and Reinstalling the new version
5. Using the new Android ADT Studio
6. Removing the SDK's and downloading all the new SDK's

I am getting very frustrated and 7500 lines of code in, I dont feel like just starting over. Any suggestions on what steps i should take next?

This is the console error I am receiving:

```html
[2014-11-08 17:48:57 - ZombieBird-android] Dx 
trouble processing "java/io/BufferedInputStream.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2014-11-08 17:48:57 - ZombieBird-android] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-11-08 17:48:57 - ZombieBird-android] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed in eclipse? I mean the plugins that you are using with your project. I remember I had that problem. I had new relic plugin installed for eclipse which I was using with my Android project. When I right click on the project and updated new relic, this problem went away. Try updating any plugins you have just for being on safe side.

Comment: Did you try clean project and building automatically

Comment: I have cleaned the project several times, it doesnt work. And as far as I know I dont have any plugins